# Javascript: JSON: Get value of a field

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string as follows:

`

```
var json_string = 
[
{"ColumnName": "Column1", "Counts": 5, "Percentages": 30},
{"ColumnName": "Column2", "Counts": 10, "Percentages": 20},
{"ColumnName": "Column3", "Counts": 7, "Percentages": 40},
{"ColumnName": "Column4", "Counts": 45, "Percentages": 12},
{"ColumnName": "Column5", "Counts": 32, "Percentages": 32}
]
```

`

How do I get the value Column4's Counts value?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this: `json_string[3]["Counts"]` or `json_string.find(a => a.ColumnName === "Column4").Counts;`